# Selectively exposing methods based on constructor used?

Tags: c#, constructor, decorator

Is it possible to selectively chose (with a decorator maybe?) what methods are exposed to an object based on a constructor that is called?

For example my class has 2 constructors, an empty one and one that passes in a file path string.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly string _filePath;
    public MyClass()
    {

    }

    public MyClass(string filePath)
    {
         _filePath = filePath
    }

    public Export()
    {
        var fi = new FileInfo(_filePath);
    }
}
```

Is it possible that when I create a new MyClass object that only if I use the constructor with the parameter to expose the Export method?

```
var myClass = new MyClass();
//myClass.Export() not available

var myClass = new MyClass(@"C:\");
//myClass.Export() is available
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a sign that you should have two different types.  Perhaps they both should be sub-types of a parent type (possibly abstract) or perhaps one should simply extend the other.

Then you can construct an instance of the appropriate type based on whether or not you have a string.  The type with a string can have an additional method.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {

    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        //todo do stuff
    }
}

public class BetterMyClass : MyClass
{
    private readonly string _filePath;

    public BetterMyClass(string filePath)
    {
        _filePath = filePath;
    }

    public void Export()
    {
        var fi = new FileInfo(_filePath);
    }
}
```

And then your usage works just fine:

```
var myClass = new MyClass();
//myClass.Export(); //syntax error

var myClass2 = new BetterMyClass(@"C:\");
myClass.Export(); //works
```

Comment: You would still have the problem of knowing which type you are using.  It's a compile-time problem, in other words.

Comment: @RobertHarvey In the context showed he doesn't need to declare the variable as the type of the parent; it can be the more derived type, so I don't see the problem.

Comment: The problem, as I see it, is that if you already know the type of the object, then all of this is moot, and if you don't know the type, then you can't say it is any particular derived type.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Why wouldn't he not know the type?  There is no indication, based on the example usage, that that isn't the case here.  He knows at compile time whether or not he's supplying a string.  It's not like it's dynamic behavior.

Comment: @Servy Thanks, this is what I thought I would have to do, I just didn't want to make a separate class that did similar logic.

Comment: @collinszac10 That's what the inheritance is there to help with.  You can added the new functionality and bring the common functionality along for the ride.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly.  You could:

1. Create a factory method that returns an object of type `IMyInterface`, and then attempt to cast to the type containing the method you wish to expose.  The cast will fail if the object is not the type exposing the method.  Or..
2. Using a `dynamic` object.  The method call will fail at runtime if the method does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, just not in the way you are showing here. You would want to create a new class that has only a default constructor and no `Export` method. Then create a second class that inherits from the first and have a constructor that requires the `string` and also exposes the `Export` method.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    { }
}

public class MyOtherClass : MyClass
{
    private readonly string value;

    public MyOtherClass(string value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public string Export() { return this.value; }
}
```

If you absolutely must have the selectivity, which is a silly design decision in my opinion, then you would want to go with a type that is built at runtime using code generation that either does or does not implement the method.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, no, this cannot be done in the way you mean.  If you could, the compiler would generally have no way to know if the method in question was valid for the object in question.  It would then have to check at run-time.  If you called the method when not available, you would receive a runtime exception.  You can throw an exception yourself based on a flag set in the constructor.

Ultimately, however, it's likely that what you really want is a subclass which has additional options.  That would be a safer way to enable this type of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using the factory pattern and returning a different interface

```
public interface IExportInterface
{
    void Export();
}

public interface INoExportInterface
{
    //Other methods
}

internal class MyClass : IExportInterface, INoExportInterface
{
    private readonly string _filePath;

    public MyClass()
    {
    }

    public MyClass(string filePath)
    {
        _filePath = filePath;
    }

    public void Export()
    {
        var fi = new FileInfo(_filePath);
    }
}

public class MyClassFactory
{
    public static IExportInterface GetMyClass(string filePath)
    {
        return new MyClass(filePath);
    }

    public static INoExportInterface GetMyClass()
    {
        return new MyClass();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that you'll either have to expose all of MyClass methods in both interfaces, or cast the return object back to MyClass to get access to MyClass methods, which defeats the purpose (because it exposes both interfaces).